# How to get Q & A of a webform submission?

Tags: 8, webforms

Main goal is to get user filled in form into a pdf. Got my pdf & sending it with email. But I cant figure out how to get Q & A from a submission. I have sid of submission. I tried

```
      $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');
  $webform_submission = $storage->loadByProperties([
    'entity_type' => 'webform',
    'entity_id' => 'questionnaire',
  ]);
  $submission_data = array();
  foreach ($webform_submission as $submission) {
    $submission_data[] = $submission->getData();
  }
```

Webform is not attached to node.

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to understand your question.  Are you asking how do I load a single webform submission by its sid? Or are you trying to load all the webform submissions for a specific webform node?

Comment: Hi Jrockowitz, I want to load a single webform submission by its sid. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Drupal 8, webform submissions are content entities so you just need to call...

```
\Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($sid)
```

Comment: How do I get Q label and A label? only getting value ids

Comment: You are going to have to load the Q and A element via \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::getElement($key) and use the element's #title and #options or for Likert element's the #questions and #answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');
$sid = 10; //Replace this value with your dynamic sid value
$submission = webform_get_submissions(array('sid' => $sid));
$nid = $submission[$sid]->nid;

$web_submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
$node = node_load($nid);
$output = webform_submission_render($node, $web_submission, NULL, 'html');

print $output;
```

Comment: I think that would work for drupal 7.

Comment: Yes, You are correct the above code will work for Drupal 7. Please check my another answer for Drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for Drupal 8:

```
 $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform_submission');
 $webform_submission = $storage->loadByProperties([
    'entity_type' => 'node', //Entity type = node
    'entity_id' => 1234, // Your Dynamic Node ID
 ]);
 $submission_data = array();
 foreach ($webform_submission as $submission) {
    $submission_data[] = $submission->getData();
 }
```